# big bug: gedit doesn't open, sh makes sh in infinite loop

Tags: process, console, gtk, sh, gedit

so, my gedit doesn't open anymore: in command line it shows its classical amount of typical warnings, then stops at a certain point and doesn't do anything else; there below the whole of its output before it (appears to) freeze in the terminal:

```
(gedit:25142): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:544:12: Expected '('

(gedit:25142): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1039:0: Junk at end of value

(gedit:25142): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: button.css:41:13: Expected '('

(gedit:25142): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: button.css:46:29: Expected ',' in color definition

(gedit:25142): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: button.css:98:16: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(gedit:25142): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: button.css:98:24: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(gedit:25142): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: toolbar.css:34:23: Not a valid image

(gedit:25142): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: toolbar.css:93:22: Not a valid image

(gedit:25142): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: popover.css:27:4: Junk at end of value

(gedit:25142): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: popover.css:37:17: Expected '('

(gedit:25142): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: albumlistview.css:26:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
```

i noticed in my system monitor, that one `sh` process was creating what i suppose are subprocesses, but of itself, in infinite loop, that is, one sh creating a 'kid sh' and so on, and impossible by the way to stop it although of course for now it doesn't bother me.

anyways, i'd like my gedit back! ^^ i tried to rename the plugin folder to see if it would load without them. (didn't work)

it indeed happens that i was working on a plugin at the time it began to go mad, but it perfectly worked the very last time i opened it, and i haven't changed the plugin between the last good opening and the moment when gedit bugged.

one other important data though: since i was debugging my plugin, i tried (how i thought worked) [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505594/how-to-stop-gedit-and-other-programs-from-outputting-gtk-warnings-and-the-like) to remove the abovementioned stupid warnings of gedit.
what i then did:

created a foo.sh file, with inside:

```
_supress() {
  eval "$1() { \$(which $1) \"\$@\" 2>&1 | tr -d '\r' | grep -v \"$2\"; }"
}

_supress gedit "WARNING"
```

following the running of this file, `gedit` didn't work at all as i wanted; and since i already had one opened gedit at the time, it kept showing me up that opened gedit window, then returning to bash, after precisely showing the above warnings and no more.

but then at the time (when i tried `gedit` after `foo.sh`), it returned to bash (after showing me up the opened gedit), while now it doesn't, it only stays running without doing anything visible, "waiting" for ctrl+C.

i obviously missed a clue anyhow on the method of above; i tried other versions, among which:

```
eval "gedit() { \$(which gedit) \"\$@\" 2>&1 | tr -d '\r' | grep -v \"WARNING\"; }"
```

again, didn't work;

that's when i realized that, once i closed the last opened gedit window, gedit didn't open anymore at all (aside the above warnings and the staying on the spot);

my sys monitor then told me what i said above (sh self creating in infinite loop, i guess not a coincidence). i tried to restart the whole computer: at reboot it was same story

i'm a bit desperate, and configured gedit well enough for that a total re installation be a complete personal tragedy :(

waiting for help! thanks in advance :)

EDIT: it's kindofa big problem however bc i'm already at +12,000 processes in less than half an hour, and my kernel seems to only allow +32000:

```
>cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
32768
```

i don't know though if those sh would show up if i don't open gedit at all on reboot... am gonna try.

EDIT: good news, `sh` didn't loop again at restart, so i'm pretty sure it's connected to the bug of gedit, and would begin if i retried to reopen gedit.

EDIT: another thing: got no problem at all if running it on root; of course then i don't have all of my personal configuration, but it means it's only "my" gedit that's bugging, though i don't exactly know where would be defined the difference between the two instances... (as obvious from above, i'm fairly newbie on bash&co)

Comment: The above warnings are generated by your GTK+ theme so what about fixing that istead of blaming gedit for every misconfiguration you have on your system?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with an empty config directory:

```
mv $HOME/.config/gedit $HOME/.config/gedit.crap
```

and re-add bit by bit the old directory content to `$HOME/.config/gedit` to seek the real culprit.

If you have messed up also the system configuration you should reinstall gedit from scratch.